# При сборе данных из всех карточек на сайте и в дальнейшем сборе данных из них вылетает ошибка

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup

ResultSet object has no attribute 'find'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call `find_all()` when you meant to call `find()`?

```
import requests

headers={
    'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    'accept': '*/*'
}
url="https://www.holodilnik.ru/smartphones_gadgets/smartphones/?page=1"

responce = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(responce.text, 'lxml')
data = soup.find_all("div", class_="col-12")

for i in data:
    name = data.find("span", itemprop="name").text
    price = data.find("div", class_="price").text
    print(name + ": " + price)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?
```

Если прочесть ошибку всё более чем очевидно.
Ты объявляешь цикл через `for i in data`, а затем обращаешься к `data`. Зачем тебе цикл тогда?
Надо так:

```python
for i in data:
    name = i.find("span", itemprop="name").text  #<====== i вместо data
    price = i.find("div", class_="price").text   #<====== i вместо data
    print(name + ": " + price)
```

А это тебя приведёт к следующей ошибке:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Поэтому надо проверять есть нахождение или нет!

```python
for i in data:
    name = i.find("span", itemprop="name")
    price = i.find("div", class_="price")
    if name != None and price != None:
        print("{}: {}".format(name.text,price.text))
```